# HTML/DOM: Mouse-events to change button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, mouseevent

In IE9, this code does not change the size of button as intended...

```
<html><head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function fun1()
    {
        alert("clicked");
        document.form1.chk1.disabled=true;
    }
    function m1()
        {
            document.form1.chk1.width=60;
        }
    function m2()
        {
            document.form1.chk1.width=40;
        }
</script>
</head><body>
<form name="form1"><!-- creating radio button group -->
    <input type="button" name="chk1" value="red" onClick="fun1()"
    onMouseOver="m1()" onMouseOut="m2()">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there was this style attribute missing in your code. try replacing this

```
document.form1.chk1.style.width="60%";
```

this worked with me

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work not only in IE9 but, for example, in FF13 and Chrome19.
To workaround this problem, you can try to replace your `m1()` and `m2()` functions as:

```
function m1()
{
    document.form1.chk1.style.width=60+"px";
}
function m2()
{
    document.form1.chk1.style.width=40+"px";
}​
```